# How pass an Array of type CustomClass to a method called by a buttons OnClick?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to pass `Hackable`s (custom class) into a mini-game within the main game depending on the button that is pressed. However, onclick doesn't list my method that takes `Hackable[] hackables` as a parameter. I think it might be struggeling with the parameter type - my custom class `hackable`. Any ideas how to solve this?

## More information

I have a script that runs the entire time. Only if the "hacking-panel" is open, the script runs a small mini-game. Before the panel is opened, I want to set the objects (`hackable`s) that are hacked if the player succeeds at finishing the mini-game.

I also thought about creating this mini-game everytime a hack is started, but I wasn't sure how this would work in unity. In every case I need to pass the `hackable`s into a method or constructor in order to know what's beeing hacked.

Comment: You cant add parameters to onclick events. You have have an onclick call something else using parameters however.

Comment: given you already agreed and used the answer below which was exactly what i said.. why?

Comment: All good. The solution below is not yet working for me, but only after my comment I realised that even though it still doesn't work, the question itself is answered and my current problem is a new one. Therefore ignore my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick method doesn’t support custom class parameters. You can only pass primitive types, strings, or UnityEngine.Object types1.

One possible solution is to use delegates or lambda expressions to wrap your method call with the custom class parameter. For example, you can do something like this:

```
// Assuming you have a reference to your button and your hackables array
button.onClick.AddListener(() => YourMethod(hackables));
```

This way, you can pass your hackables array to your method without using the onclick parameter1.

Comment: I placed this code in `start()` of another game object. I think that is what you intended. However, `YourMethod` doesn't get executed. I think that's a new question, therefore I will close this one and accept your answer.