# Unity: Why is the button listener not triggered when the button is pressed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Following https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html I implemented:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Hacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print(button);
        button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        print("Pressed");
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");
    }

}
```

When I now start the game and press the button, the following appears in the console:

```
mybutton (UnityEngine.UI.Button)
```

I would've expected to get the TaskOnClick print and log, but I only got the `print(button);`. Why's the added listener ignored? I am very sure that I pressed the correct button, because it is the only button with this name in the game.

This question is somewhat connected to [How pass an Array of type CustomClass to a method called by a buttons OnClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352721/how-pass-an-array-of-type-customclass-to-a-method-called-by-a-buttons-onclick)

## What I have tried

Using `UnityEngine.UIElements.Button` instead, but I get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` directly at the assignment line:

```cs
replaces button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
button.clicked += TaskOnClick;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `using UnityEngine.UIElements` and `clicked`.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;  // add this
using TMPro;

public class Hacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print(button);
        button.clicked += TaskOnClick;
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        print("Pressed");
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");
    }

}
```

You may need to reassign the button in the editor, because we changed its type from `UnityEngine.UI.Button` to `UnityEngine.UIElements.Button`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Changing the buttons did change something, but now I get another error. I added the new info to my question.

Comment: if you're getting NullReferenceException, chances are that you forgot to assign the button again, just like I said in my answer "You may need to reassign the button in the editor, because we changed its type from UnityEngine.UI.Button to UnityEngine.UIElements.Button"